# How to let a trigger work outside of its transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I think that trigger functions somehow operate inside of a transaction. Is there any way of issuing statements from within the trigger function and make the result visible to others before the trigger transaction is finished?

I have some lengthy trigger operations (> 100 ms) for updating user access rights. In a stress test I discovered a problem when a user (i.e. an app) asks the server for new events during this trigger operation.

My thought is to write out a timestamp to a table in the start of the trigger so that external requests can be adjusted according to this information, but I need this timestamp to be visible instantly.

I'll try explain a bit deeper:

Our app only asks for changed data since the last request. When the answer is delivered to the app a new timestamp (called lastUpdate) is also delivered for the app to remember. When the app want's to refresh data again the *lastUpdate* timestamp is sent in the request.

Example of problem scenario:

1. app requests new data from the server
2. app receives data along with lastUpdate=01:00:00.000
3. Half a second later the app asks for changes since lastUpdate
4. Sometimes later the app requests more data with lastUpdated=01:00:00.500

But neither the server nor the app knew that a trigger was updating some data at this exact moment. To ensure that this data gets delivered correctly upon request the trigger timestamps it with **now()**.

The trigger started at 00:59:59:999, so this will be the value of the **modified_at** column. The trigger finished its job at 01:00:01.000, so the changes weren't visible at the request time.

There are no changes since 01:00:00.500 in the database, so the request in step 4 will get no data. The changes we wanted to fetch is timestamped at 00:59:59:99.

This is an edge case and I stumbled upon it when I forced the app to refresh every 100 ms.

If I could somehow communicate from the trigger to the outside world at the start of the trigger that a trigger is executing I think I could solve this.

The concept of lastUpdate is probably quite common to fetch new data from a known timestamp. Is there also a common way to solve my problem?

BTW, I'm using Postgres 9.6.

Comment: You're looking for "autonomous commit". Search for that and you'll learn more. It's not directly supported by postgres but there are workarounds, albeit not lovely. However, it won't solve your race condition.

Comment: Your problem have a simple solution: just don't change your app's (cached) `lastUpdated` value when the server responds with *no changes since the provided lastUpdated date*. So in your example scenario, the 4. point will be: *Sometimes later the app requests more data with lastUpdated=01:00:00.000*.

Comment: @pozs. Thanks. But I don't think it will work. What if the app receives some other data. I'd have to cache the lastUpdated, but could miss the trigger created data anyway.

Comment: I just discovered "Advisory locks". This kind of lock seems to be useful for this exact problem. I'll get back when I know how it works out.

Comment: @Michael that's the point: when a transaction is not committed yet, you won't see changed data anyway.

Comment: @pozs. But there are a lot of events that could change data. The trigger is only one event. Mostly data will be updated from other apps, after which my app need to receive the updated/new data.

Comment: @Michael still, the point is that data, which belongs together should change together (f.ex. the `lastUpdated` column & other columns in that table). See. f.ex. [how HTTP handles this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since). -- Ongoing modifications shouldn't be considered at all: there is a chance that the ongoing modification will be reverted by a roll-back f.ex.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding.. You suggest that I don't cache lastUpdated if I receive no data. But what if I received some data in step 3 in my example. I'd have to cache lastUpdated in this case. On the next request I'd miss the updates done by the trigger. If the trigger could set modified_at to the time when the trigger is done instead of when it starts all would be great.

Comment: Advisory lock solves my issue. They are really cool. I'll put together an answer on my own question in a couple of days if anyone is interested. Learned about the locks here: http://blog.nordeus.com/dev-ops/postgresql-locking-revealed.htm